# Conjecture and prove a formula for finding the size of composition whose sum is n

Tags: number-theory

A composition of a natural number n is an ordered list of positive integers whose sum is
n. Let c(n) be the number of compositions of n. Conjecture and then prove a formula for
c(n) for all n ≥ 1.

I found $2^{n-1}$, but I don't know how to prove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place separators in $n-1$ places between $n$ elements. That's $2^{n-1}$ independent binary choices, which correspond bijectively to the compositions of $n$.

Alternatively, think of $n$ written as

$$
n=\underbrace{1+\cdots+1}_{\text{$n$ summands}}
$$

and choose which of these $n-1$ plus signs to insert between the $1$s. The numbers resulting from these additions form a composition of $n$.